# Error on updating Craft install with Sprout vendor files

Tags: plugins, install

I was updating an Craft install on Mediatemple server yesterday. Im now getting the following error:

Cannot use barrelstrength\sproutbase\app\import\base\FieldImporter as FieldImporter because the name is already in use

I tried creating a new install but I get the same error - any ideas what I can do to rectify?

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same error and tried so many times install/uninstall but couldn't succeed. In my case, it was basically php 7 version compatibility issue.

You should change your php version to php 7.1.16 or higher, if using lower like php 7.0

Fixed by Dev: https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-forms/issues/195

Code to be modified: https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-base/commit/5e8ce5eb9b1815d1d2a66ed69664a890271d6620

Regards

Ankit Chauhan